# Reduce Photo Size in Android before uploading it on server

Tags: android, image

I want to reduce photo size in android before uploading it on server. How to do it without any effect like optimization on image ?

I also want to allow user to crop image so I found some tutorials but by comments, i came to know that User gets error in some android versions. So Is there any way to allow user to crop images which can be workable in all android versions.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 2):

Use following code to crop and reduce the size of image while picking it from Gallery of your device

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    // photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 512);
                    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 512);
                    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tt.jpg");
```

Hope it helps..Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this It working for me:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(String path) {

Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
InputStream in = null;
try {
    final int IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 1200000; // 1.2MP
    in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);

    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
    in.close();



    int scale = 1;
    while ((o.outWidth * o.outHeight) * (1 / Math.pow(scale, 2)) > 
          IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
       scale++;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "scale = " + scale + ", orig-width: " + o.outWidth + ", 
       orig-height: " + o.outHeight);

    Bitmap b = null;
    in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(uri);
    if (scale > 1) {
        scale--;
        // scale to max possible inSampleSize that still yields an image
        // larger than target
        o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inSampleSize = scale;
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

        // resize to desired dimensions
        int height = b.getHeight();
        int width = b.getWidth();
        Log.d(TAG, "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ",
           height: " + height);

        double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
                / (((double) width) / height));
        double x = (y / height) * width;

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x, 
           (int) y, true);
        b.recycle();
        b = scaledBitmap;

        System.gc();
    } else {
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    }
    in.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "bitmap size - width: " +b.getWidth() + ", height: " + 
       b.getHeight());
    return b;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bitmap decodeAndResizeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }


convert your bitmap object to file on=bject and use these ::->

File file = new File("your bitmap path ");
            Bitmap bmpp = decodeAndResizeFile(file);
```